# Como formatar uma data de bytes(Pyhon)

Tags: python

Boa tarde tenho a seguinte duvida, gostava de printar a data da seguinte maneira por exemplo 5/24/2019 mas o que esta acontecer é o seguinte

```
print(date)
Data: b'20290510113138Z'
```

tenho o seguinte código

```
cert =crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM,open(cert_file).read())
date = cert.get_notAfter()
print("Data:",date)
```

encontrei um código que resolve o problema mas não sei como implementar no meu código alguma sugestão?

```
datetime.strtime(cert.get_notAfter().decode('ascii'), '%Y%m%d%H%M%SZ')
```

Comment: a data em bytes do seu exemplo é qual? 10/5/2029? pq. se for 24/5/2019, está bem difícil de matar a charada -

Comment: a data é 5/10/2029 mas também pode ser 10/5/2029 não tem problema

Comment: hmm.. 10 de MAIO! por que se for 5 de OUTUBRO, tem problema sim, como o protocolo mais bugado da história. (mas o exemplo que você colocou extrai o mês na ordem certa)

Comment: na próxima pergunta, ao colocar exemplos dos dados que você tem, e da saída desejada, por favor coloque a saída que seria resultante _daqueles_ dados de entrada, não algo completamente desconexo. Uma data-hora em bytes poderia estar codificada de forma binária, e o processo de conversão seria completamente diferente, por exemplo.

Answer (score 3):

```
import datetime

cert =crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM,open(cert_file).read())
enc_date = cert.get_notAfter().decode("ascii")
date = datetime.strptime(enc_date, '%Y%m%d%H%M%SZ')

print("Data:",date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"))
```

Mantendo a darta no estilo estadosunidense, com o mês antes do dia, como está no seu exemplo.

As chamadas "strptime" (o p de "parse") e "strftime" ("f" de "format") convertem strings em objetos de data-hora  e vice-versa - as chamadas existem na biblioteca padrão do sistema operacional, disponíveis em C e o Python expõe uma versão das mesmas em sua própria biblioteca padrão.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: eu já tinha feito algo desse género mas dava sempre o seguinte erro                                            'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: sim - o nome do método é "strftime", não "strtime" - um erro de digitação em algum ponto - nesse caso você fez bem de perguntar.